# Super-imposed polylines are not aligned

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, polyline

I'm currently working on an `Android` app to order a cab. The core of the app is based on a fragment with a `MapView` inside and some other views.

Once the user has entered its pick up address and drop off address, i'm able to draw a curved polyline between those two coordinates using this algorithm [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/curved-lines-on-google-maps-2938bbb15f6a).

Now I want to add an animation to visualize the direction of the trip. It looks like  this [image: Trip animation]

As you may guess, I use 2 polylines, one "background" polyline that is static and one "foreground" polyline that is animated.
To animate the 2nd polyline, I just take a sublist of points of my first polyline, according to the animation fraction of my animator and update it at each animation update

```
override fun onAnimationUpdate(animation: ValueAnimator) {
    val backgroundPolylineSize = backgroundPolyline.points.size
    val foregroundEnd = ceil(animation.animatedFraction * backgroundPolylineSize).toInt()
    val foregroundPointCounts = (backgroundPolylineSize * 0.1).toInt() // 10% of the total trip
    foregroundPolyline.points = backgroundPolyline.points.subList(
        max(0, foregroundEnd - foregroundPointCounts), foregroundEnd
    )
}
```

The result is OK, but not perfect. In fact, I noted that the two polylines (which are superposed) are not correctly aligned

[image: polyline shift].

I have no idea why, I use the same points for the two polylines, but it looks like they are drawn differently.

Here are the polyline options I used

```
val polylineOptions = PolylineOptions()
        .color(backgroundColor)
        .width(POLYLINE_WIDTH)
        .geodesic(false)
        .jointType(JointType.ROUND)
        .zIndex(0f)
        .addAll(polylineCoordinates)
    backgroundPolyline = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions)

    val foregroundPolylineOptions = PolylineOptions()
        .color(foregroundColor)
        .width(FOREGROUND_POLYLINE_WIDTH)
        .jointType(JointType.ROUND)
        .geodesic(false)
        .zIndex(1f)
    foregroundPolyline = map.addPolyline(foregroundPolylineOptions)
```

Comment: You are using less multiplier or number of samples for drawing the line. Decrease the 0.1 to a suitable lower number like 50-100 sample which corresponds to values of 0.05 to 0.01. this will help you get better precision and more improved curve. Also in my understanding the value for `.geodesic(false)` should be `.geodesic(true)` for you to have the smoother black line.